# Make only a part of ListView element change when clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview

I find it very difficult to explain my problem to a search engine, or to anyone for that matter. I'll do my best to explain it. I have a ListView and I made custom views for elements in the ListView. This is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_dropdown_style"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how the ListView looks like:

[image]

As you you can see, the divider is always grey but when ListView element is clicked, the divider turns blue. This is the problem. I only want the white part of the element to turn green and the grey divider to stay grey.

This is the spinner_dropdown_style (selector):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/button_color_pressed" />
</selector>
```

How do I make it so that selector will only work on the white area and the grey divider stays grey even when element is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `android:divider="@layout/id of layout"` this line in your list view

make another layout for

`<View android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow" />`

add remove  element.

hope this will help out

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem, there is just one wrong detail in your solution. The divider SHOULDN'T be a layout file. It should be either a drawable or a color. When I added a layout file as a divider, the application crashed.

Answer (score 0):

add to your list view in xml:

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

The ListView has its own selector that it applies to selected items.  You are just toggling the background of the TextView, not the entire selected item.  To do that, you can try adding this to your listview:

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:listSelector="@color/button_color_pressed"
```